# Phalcon2 module app routing

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

just installed Phalcon2 and working around multi-module app.

I've have such structure.

[image: I've have such structure.]

And my index file http://pastebin.com/zqaRKCdC

When navigating to / , see the front-module index controller, but if I go to /admin, see the same. Maybe anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

P.S One of Module.php - http://pastebin.com/CpGDSuyE

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not that you are not pointing to the same Controller and Action ?

Comment: Can you show us your router service configuration?